# Normal map editing as ordinary image

Tags: texturing

After baking from the photogammetry mesh I've got the normal map wich has areas that need to be corrected. Can I edit the normal map in Photoshop as the ordinary image - apply patching, bluring, clone stamp and other similar tools?
I'm worring about the fact that the normal map encodes the normalized vectors and after editing these vectors will became denormalized and any artifacts can be appeared...

[image]

Comment: yes you can, just use the good colors, use the eyedropper

Comment: @moonboots The using of eyedropper tool is understood, but what will be happened if I blure some part of the normal map or use the clonnig with soft borders? Nothing will be broken?

Comment: if you blur then the 3D relief will be softer, if you put other colors than the normal spectrum you'll have dark spots

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the normal map as much as you want, just use the good spectrum of colors, so use the eyedropper. If you blur the image then the 3D relief will be softer, if you put other colors than the normal spectrum you'll have dark spots:

[image]